# How can i obtain the size of files uploaded with Media Library in my Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, size, media, media-library

I want to know the size of the uploaded files in my Laravel Course project.
Media library store the size of every file uploaded to the database, but how can I know which file is related to which course?

For example, I have three Courses in my database and if I upload some posts with files, [the files are stored in the media table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEcz5.jpg). But it is not clear which files are related to which Course.

Comment: `model_type` and `model_id` tell you which course has which image. In your case, the Course with `id= 464` has the image `Capture2.JPG` attached. I suppose you are using `spatie/medialibrary`, which has [documentation](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/basic-usage/retrieving-media/) on how to get related media

Comment: So how can we understand post that store in model_type related to which course?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. That table does _not_ show the relation of posts and courses.